# VSTO Add-In : How to make one add-in from 3 add-ins for 3 Outlook versions?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have three addins that do roughly the same thing, but one is for Outlook 2010, one for 2013 and one for 2016.
I've been researching for a couple days how to (and if it is at all possible to) make it so I have only one that would install on the three versions of Outlook.

I know that the add-in for Outlook 2016 uses a few objects (and maybe events) that don't exist in Outlook 2010, but I'm pretty sure that's not that bad, that I could just verify the version when the start-up event fires and go from there ?

I'm very new at VSTO Add-Ins, so I haven't yet tried anything, but from what I read, all of them should be able to work on any version, provided a few tweaks?
Problem is: I'm not even sure of that because I've seen a lot of different views on this (people saying it's possible and others saying "hum no, just don't") and even if I was I think what I understood is there might be problems of compatibility because of the PIAs ?

I just have no idea where to go from here, actually.

Answer (score 1):

VSTO allows creating add-ins that support multiple Office versions. Read more about that in the [Run solutions in different versions of Microsoft Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/running-solutions-in-different-versions-of-microsoft-office?view=vs-2019) article.

Note, you need to use PIAs that correspond to the lowest version of Office supported. In that case, you can make sure no runtime exception is fired by a member which doesn't exist in a new Office version. At runtime, you may check the host application version and use the late-binding technology represented by Reflection in the .net development world, see [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=netframework-4.8) for more information.

Also, you may consider using [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php). They allow creating version-neutral add-ins out of the box.